# How to iterate or loop in one go?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if someone could tell me what I am missing as I want to run a program which checks the list of file from a directory then prints the following before it deletes:

1. Created, modified time
2. Name & extension
3. Size

However, I am unable to loop the size and the cereated, modified time instead it will list the files, but would show the size and created, modified time for the directory.

```
import os.path, time, fnmatch


# get file info including time
def get_File_Info():
    print("Last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime('my file path')))
    print("Created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime('my file path')))

#get file size
def get_File_Size():
    file_size = os.stat('my file path')
    print("Size of file :", file_size.st_size, "bytes")

# Get file name and  Extension
for file_name in os.listdir('my file path'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, '*.*'):
        print(file_name)
        print(get_File_Info())
        print(get_File_Size())
```

Comment: If you always call the functions with `'my file path'` as argument, then you're going to get the same result. If you want to get the information about a different file, you'll need to pass *that* as an argument, not the directory name

Comment: I think you should be passing `os.path.join('my file path', file_name)` as an argument to your functions, then use that path to get the ctime/mtime/size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions need to take the file pathname as an argument.

```
import os, time, glob

# get file info including time
def get_File_Info(filename):
    print("Last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(filename)))
    print("Created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(filename)))

#get file size
def get_File_Size(filename):
    file_size = os.stat(filename)
    print("Size of file :", file_size.st_size, "bytes")

# Get file name and  Extension
for file_name in glob.glob('my file path/*.*'):
    print(os.path.basename(file_name))
    get_File_Info(file_name)
    get_File_Size(file_name)
```

You can also use `glob.glob()` to just get a list of filenames matching a pattern, instead of mixing `os.listdir()` with `fnmatch.fnmatch()`.

You also shouldn't print the result of the `get_XXX` functions, since those functions do their own printing and don't return anything.

Comment: Oh thank you  `print("Created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(filename)))` 
  still shows the file directory instead of the individual files not sure why